# Better Syntax / Alternatives for method chaining

Tags: python

I know that Python does not explicitly enable or have features that allow for method chaining, but I want to do the following:

```
infile = wave.open(
         fileName="sample.wav",
         type='DOUBLE').Emphasize().Compress()
```

The problem being is, if I used, let's say the following:

```
wav.open(Emphasize(Compress("blahh", "blahh")));
```

Then:

1) The code, to me, looks a lot more uglier than Method Chaining

2) I need to be able to fetch the data before I Emphasize and Compress it.

Any ideas to better structure this code?

Comment: Python does not prevent method chaining either. SQLAlchemy uses it just fine.

Comment: I think your code looks fine. The only limitation with method chaining is an exception being thrown if a previous method fails to return quality data, you don't have a chance to catch it.

Comment: I use chaining all the time in python, when it makes sense: line.strip().split("\t")[0] or something like that. That doesn't mean that some functions are written weirdly that don't allow it when it feels like it should, but that's probably not python problem as much as a library developer with a different philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

Don't fear the temporary variables.  They're easier to debug (with chaining, if there's a bug, you end up pulling it apart anyway), and easier to understand (and easy reading beats easy coding in practicality).  Your future maintainer will thank you.

IOW, something like this is better than chaining (but you should use more meaningful variable names) :

```
compressed = Compress("blahh", "blahh")
emphasized = Emphasize(compressed)
wav.open(emphasized)
```

http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/alanperlis177188.html